# Ubuntu 18.04 with two NIC in two networks with netplan

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, dns

I'm trying to setup my Ubuntu 18.04 Server with two NIC in two networks. After hours of work I'm totally frustrated.

My netplan is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
ens33:
  addresses: [10.168.1.26/24]
  gateway4: 10.168.1.1
  nameservers:
    addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
ens34: 
  addresses: [10.170.1.26/24]
  nameservers:
    addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

When I ping from ens33 into the internet, it works fine.
From ens34 fails. How can I change that?

When I ping ens33 from any client in network 10.168.1.0/24 it works fine, trying to ping ens34 fails.

The other way around: When I ping ens34 from any client in network 10.170.1.0/24 it works fine, trying to ping the ens33 fails.

Could you please give me advice, how to deal with that problem?

Cheers
Mattias

After the first comment I changed as below, but without a positiv effect.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses: [10.168.1.26/24]
      gateway4: 10.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    ens34: 
      addresses: [10.170.1.26/24]
      gateway4: 10.170.1.1    
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

ens34 has no gateway, thus no internet access.

10.168.x.x and 10.170.x.x are on different subnets, they can't talk to each other by default. You need to get both NICs on the same network (the same as the other client machines) and use the same gateway.

Test it with setting a static IP. 
https://websiteforstudents.com/switch-static-ip-address-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

Comment: Normally you can only have one "default gateway". What is your purpose with 2 nics? Create a router? Create a bridge?...

Comment: I would like to have the ability to reach the server from two different subnets. My intention is not to build a router or a firewall.